# Do Session variables get assigned even after tab is closed?

Tags: php, session

If a user goes to a PHP script in their browser, and then closes it midway through it completing, will the standard php session variables ($_SESSION) still get assigned as the execution of the script was already initiated?

Comment: why not test it?

Comment: Yes It will be assigned. Unless you manually destroy the session or if you clear your browser's cache (not sure about clearing browser cache), your session value remains.

Comment: If you're script takes 30 seconds for instance, and you assign the session right at the end of the script, and you cancel half way through, the session isn't going to be set because it hasn't reached that far into your script yet. If you set the session at the very start of the script, it will be set. It all depends on how far the script has been processed and where you save to the session.

Comment: @KishenNagaraju your answers is a valid answer for this question. undelete. And Phil makes a good point re: output buffering and assigning session at the end of a script (although I'm sure this isn't the best way of doing it, it's possible)

Comment: Depends - on configuration. You’ll want to start with http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes It will be assigned. Unless you manually destroy the session or if you clear your browser's cache (not sure about clearing browser cache), your session value remains.

Comment: This looks a lot like a comment and not an answer

Comment: Ok. Changing it to comment.